# Use code to add info to database but getting {'object':'error', 'status': 400, 'code': 'invalid_json', 'message': 'Error parsing JSON body.'}

Tags: python, notion-api

I am doing the [Getting Started Guide for Notion](https://developers.notion.com/docs/getting-started) using Python and I have this error occurring everytime I send in a post request:

```
{'object': 'error', 'status': 400, 'code': 'invalid_json', 'message': 'Error parsing JSON body.'}
```

Here what I have tried with my code:

```
# Notion Application
import json, requests


file = open('SECRETS.json') # Opens the file

data = json.load(file) # loads the data then stores in variable called data

# Secret here:
secret = data['id']

# Database information here:
database = data['database_tasks']

file.close() # close file

url = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages'

# Headers
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {secret}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Notion-Version': '2021-05-13'
}

# Data input
data_input = {
    "parent": { "database_id": f"{database}" },
    "properties": {
      "Name": {
        "title": [
          {
            "text": {
              "content": "Yurts in Big Sur, California"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }

  
# check request 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_input)
print(response.json())
```

I've searched up the error but I cannot see what I did wrong. I followed the cURL example that they provided on the website in python form.

Comment: Instead of "data=data_input" write "json=data_input"